# Change navbar bg color using bootstrap sass variables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, compass-sass, bootstrap-sass

Is `$navbar-default-bg` used anywhere?
I changed its value and I don't see any change in navbar background color.

Also, I did

```
$ grep -nr "navbar-default-bg" .
./sass/_bootstrap-variables.scss:342:$navbar-default-bg:                #ff0000;
./sass/_bootstrap-variables.scss:343:// $navbar-default-border:            darken($navbar-default-bg, 6.5%)
./sass/_bootstrap-variables.scss:350:// $navbar-default-link-active-bg:            darken($navbar-default-bg, 6.5%)
```

So, where is this variable used? Or how can I change the navbar bg color?

My file structure is:

```
$ tree
.
├── config.rb
├── fonts
│   └── bootstrap
│       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│       └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
├── javascripts
│   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── affix.js
│   │   ├── alert.js
│   │   ├── button.js
│   │   ├── carousel.js
│   │   ├── collapse.js
│   │   ├── dropdown.js
│   │   ├── modal.js
│   │   ├── popover.js
│   │   ├── scrollspy.js
│   │   ├── tab.js
│   │   ├── tooltip.js
│   │   └── transition.js
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   └── bootstrap-sprockets.js
├── sass
│   ├── _bootstrap-variables.scss
│   └── styles.scss
└── stylesheets
    └── styles.css
```

Comment: In variables.less it's found on line 353. So I guess the bootstrap-variables.scss file

Comment: You're searching in the wrong location.  Of course it won't be found anywhere in your project directory because that's not where the Bootstrap library files are located.

Answer (score 0):

In pure bootstrap, those variables ($navbar-default-bg, $navbar-default-border, $navbar-default-link-active-bg) are used in the [navbar.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less) file to style the default navbar.

If you change it in your _bootstrap-variables.scss file, that should update it, assuming you are pulling the rest of Bootstrap's styles in somewhere.

Comment: Without a code sample showing where you pull in the Bootstrap styles, I can't really help any further. Are you using a SASS port of Bootstrap?